# how to create global component in angular 2, So we can just add that component at one place and access in overall application

Tags: angular

We can take an example of Footer in any angular 2 application.

For, now i'm creating a component and adding that component in every component, Which is making the process lengthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was supported in beta and RC versions but not in final.

You can create a shared module that exports a component
and than add this shared module to `imports: [...]` of every module where you want to use this "global component"

Comment: Could you please provide in more detail or any link? I'm newbie to Angular 2

Comment: The question I made yours a duplicate of provides an example. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html